# Выбор ОС для embedded system

Tags: windows, android, embedded, linux

Есть некий готовый дивайс безкорпусного исполнения с тачскрином. Работает на 
базе ARM Cortex-A8. По заверениям разработчиков поддерживает 3 ос: win ce 
6.0, android, linux. Дивайс будет использоваться только как "дисплей", т.е. визуализировать опредленные данные, которые штатная сисистема не обрабатывает. Управления и  сложных расчётов не предполагается. Возникает вопрос: что выбрать в качестве 
ОС для разработки?

Критерии такие:

1. сложность разработки драйверов (возможно, придется использовать что-нибудь 
   нестандартное, скажем ацп контроллера; очевидно, чтоб это заработало на 
   уровне ОС надо будет писать драйвер);
2. сложность использования библиотек граф. интерфейса (я далек от мысли 
   делать собственные контролы типа gauge и graph);
3. ну, и в целом, если судить по вашему опыту.

Кстати отдельно стоит вопрос о тестировании разработки до его заливки на 
дивайс. Скажем, для linux предоставляется исходный код, для android'a 
snapshot, для ce - bsp исходник. Существует ли возможность запустить ОС в 
эмуляторе?

Пример того, что хотелось бы иметь на выходе:

[снимок http://www.dundas.com/Libraries/Dashboard_Gallery/sales-performance-dashboard.jpg](http://www.dundas.com/Libraries/Dashboard_Gallery/sales-performance-dashboard.jpg)
[image: снимок]

Comment: Я вам почти завидую. Перед вами поставлена офигенная задача ;)

Comment: Немного ковырялся с WinCE5.0 и много с Linux. В последнем по моему проще. 1. WinCE загружаясь съедает кучу памяти, ядро отдельно от rootfs не собрать, это один монолит. 2. В Linux общаться с аппаратурой можно из приложения пользователя, т.е. в некоторых случаях, можно обойтись без написания драйвера, т.к. драйверописательство требует некоторого уровня вхождения.

Answer (score 4):

1. Сложность разработки драйверов в целом одинаковая для всех трёх ос. Правда при использовании стандартных устройств есть шанс, что на CE заработает нахаляву, тогда как в Linux эта вероятность ниже.
2. Наличие стандартных контролов, тут всё зависит от вас. В обоих случаях вам не придётся писать их самостоятельно. В случае android это ещё и выглядеть будет весьма эстетично.
3. У меня есть только опыт с Embedded Linux и он (опыт) в целом положительный.

OC в эмуляторе - [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page). Например, в нём работает стандартный android-эмулятор. Кроме того, в этом смысле Linux-системы предпочтительнее, так как удобно запускать и отлаживать приложения на живом устройстве по сети, в том числе и само ядро.

**UPD**

Думаю, учитывя, что вы хотите такую красоту, но не хотите писать это руками, то скорее всего ваш выбор - Android. Делать такие красивости другими средствами будет намного сложнее, хотя, нет сомнений, что возможно даже с помощью тормознутого GTK.

Comment: Про запуск и отладку приложения - это возможности IDE, правильно пониманию?

Comment: Это возможности IDE и самой платформы. Удобно запускать приложение по NFS, удобно отлаживать удалённо с помощью gdb, поддержка которого имеется в IDE.

Comment: С места про производительность поподробнее) Дело в том, что даже под "обынчую" винду такие красивости работали не лучшим образом. Графики "онлайн" тупили, масштабирование сбоило. Поэтому при выборе системы производительность решения крайне важна.

Comment: Производительность андроидной графики хорошая. Под простой Linux можно было бы использовать Qt (она работает на малых системах в разы быстрее, чем GTK), но вот только не уверен с лицензией. Графика по WinCE вообще ни разу не быстрая, так что тоже не очень хороший вариант.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m Не понятно про какую "быстроту" графики идёт речь? По моему это определяется наличием нужных библиотек под платформу и аппаратурой. Для WinCE это Direct3D, для встроенного Linux обычно OpenGLES.

Comment: Direct3D под WinCE для рисования интерфейсов?

Answer (score 0):

Визуализация визуализации рознь. Как пример, [использование](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/DIY/118537/) плеера vogue в качестве монитора. Чем ближе к железу тем проще. В случае андройда, кроме драйвера к железу придется писать еще и "прокладку" в java. Зато граф интерфейс уже весь готовый есть.

Comment: Я добавил ссылки на то, что хотелось бы видеть, для большего понимания визуализации.

Comment: да, под андройд-то будет поприятнее писать всяко чем под голый линукс. win ce имхо даже рассматривать не стоит.
Кстати как вариант, весь интерфейс написать на html, инфу дергать через web-socket. В итоге от андройда вам понадобится только браузер (ну или простейшее полноэкранное приложение с контролом браузера внутри чтобы стандартные кнопки обычного браузера не показывались). Я бы так делал.

Comment: Не совсем понял, как это реализовывать. Придется ведь делать приложение, которое будет играть роль веб сервера?

Comment: При таком подходе да, придётся.

Comment: Вы же написали что "визуализировать опредленные данные, которые штатная сисистема не обрабатывает", то есть есть какая-то другая система из которой данные приходят. Ну вот там и нужно поднять простейший веб-сервер.. или не совсем веб

Answer (score 0):

Dundash Dashboard)) Ох помучался я с ним. Собственно я работал на проекте конкуренте дундаса. Для визуализации использовали JavaScript библиотеку [HightCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/); из OS тут конечно android - проблем будет меньше.

Comment: Я юзал библиотеки dundash под .net в части gauge и chart. Честно скажу - для динамичных вещей не подходит, хотя из аналогов пожалуй самая быстрая. В итоге остановились на PlotLab.
Кстати как с производительностью в итоге?

Comment: Работает достаточно шустро, даже с реал-тайм данными, а главное крос-платформенно) Не надо ни флеша ни силверлайта, только браузер.

Comment: Спасибо) Быть может, вы ещё знаете аналогичную gauge библиотеку?

Comment: Посмотрите http://www.devexpress.com/, у них очень много разных контролов, но для .NET.